# Name of this graph family?

Tags: graphs, dag

Suppose I start with a directed chain graph of length $n$:

[image]

And then I add $k$ edges, with a restriction that the result is a planar DAG:

[image]

Is there a name for this graph family?

Comment: Is $k$ at most constant or arbitrary? Can edges added to the bottom-side or only the top-side?

Comment: edges can be added to any side, the only restriction on $n$ and $k$ is that the result is a planar DAG

Answer (score 1):

Your graph class coincides with the class of Hamiltonian planar DAGs. See [1] for the undirected version of the equivalence. See also [2] for an account of the directed version.

Proof sketch: given a directed Hamiltonian path, the vertices can be moved continuously to a straight line so the planar embedding is preserved.

The underlying undirected graphs are called *[book thickness 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding)*, *2-page* or *2-stack*. This class is equivalent to the [subhamiltonian graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhamiltonian_graph).

- [1]: Frank Bernhart and Paul C Kainen. "The book thickness of a graph." *Journal of Combinatorial Theory* Series B 27.3 (1979).
- [2]: Binucci Carla et al. "Upward book embeddings of st-graphs." arXiv preprint [arXiv:1903.07966](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07966) (2019).